# How can I use different layouts for landscape and portrait orientation via Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, layout, xcode-storyboard

I try to make different sizes and positions of elements depending on the screen orientation. Part of the elements must change its position when rotating the device. I have an idea how it implement via layoutSubview method, but I would like to know how it can be implemented via Storyboard.

Example of the display elements for different orientations shown on the following diagram:
[enter link description here](http://cl.ly/image/3e2x1o3f050H)

Answer (score 1):

It will really depend how your user interface is. Sometimes you can use Autolayout and adjust the screen to your preferences and in other cases (the menu changes completely from landscape to portrait), you have to find a workaround. Most of the times I use the second option : Ive got several screens in my storyboard and I deal with autolayout changing from portrait to landscape and viceversa but other times, it´s really difficult and a challenge to use autolayout so I use separate xib files and I deal in the UIViewController rotation events with to update the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

The device orientation can be performed via coding. I just show you a way.

```
//This method will perform supported orientations which you wanna show.
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

You can also set the default orientation (like in gaming we user Landscape orientation).

```
 // The default device orientation is set LandscapeRight
    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
```

In this way you can change your device orientation. For more details you can follow apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc